# Sorting date array orderedAscending swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to sort dates in ascending order. I am able to solve the date in the format `"MM/dd/yyyy"` but when changed to this format `"dd mmm yyyy"` I get an error.

This works

```
var dateArray = [Date]()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "09/04/2016")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "01/01/2000")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "12/12/1903")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "04/23/2222")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "08/06/1957")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "11/11/1911")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "02/05/1961")!)

dateArray.sort { (date1, date2) -> Bool in
    return date1.compare(date2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

for date in dateArray {
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}
```

but this does not

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd mmm yyyy"

dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from:"01 Mar 2017")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "03 Feb 2017")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "15 Jan 1998")!)

dateArray.sort { (date1, date2) -> Bool in
    return date1.compare(date2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

for date in dateArray {
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}
```

Comment: See answer from @Sh_Khan. You can also simplify the sort to `dateArray.sort(by: <)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `MMM` isntead of `mmm`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use "MMM" instead of "mmm"**

`MMM` is The shorthand name of the month `m, mm` are for minutes

Please check this site https://nsdateformatter.com will help to understance about NSDateFormatter

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from:"01 Mar 2017")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "03 Feb 2017")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "15 Jan 1998")!)

dateArray.sort { (date1, date2) -> Bool in
    return date1.compare(date2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

for date in dateArray {
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just change the format from lowercase "mmm" to uppercase "MMM", like this:

```
var dateArray = [Date]()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from:"01 Mar 2017")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "03 Feb 2017")!)
dateArray.append(dateFormatter.date(from: "15 Jan 1998")!)

dateArray.sort { (date1, date2) -> Bool in
    return date1.compare(date2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
}

for date in dateArray {
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
}
```